# WP Как вернуть ссылку (только слаг) на пост?

Tags: php, wordpress

Подскажите, пожалуйста как в WordPress вернуть только слаг статьи
Допустим есть статья со ссылкой. http://example.com/first-post

Есть встроенная функция котарая вернет всю `<?php echo get_permalink()?>` ссылку. А как вернуть только first-post ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если в цикле, то

```
global $post; 
echo $post->post_name
```

Если вне цикла, то:

```
$post_id = 45; //id поста
$post = get_post($post_id); 
echo $post->post_name;
```